# a counter-example of Lie Group

Tags: smooth-manifolds

Is there an example of a $n$-dimensional Lie group whose left invariant $n$-form is not right invariant? As far as I know, the Lie group can't be compact. But I don't know how to construct an example.

Comment: This is the same as asking for a non-unimodular Lie group.  (Almost?) any non-reductive example will do; for example, @ThiKu's [$a x + b$ example](https://mathoverflow.net/a/311387) below, or a proper parabolic subgroup of a reductive group.

Comment: (You are right that such a Lie group cannot be compact.  There is a continuous homomorphism $G \to \mathbb R^\times$, called the modulus (or modular) function, whose non-triviality measures the failure of $G$ to be unimodular; and such a homomorphism from a compact group must be trivial.)

Comment: (I'm glad I included the weasel '[almost](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311386/a-counter-example-of-lie-group#comment776574_311386)'; the matrix group $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & * \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, which is a copy of the additive group (say of $\mathbb R$), is unipotent by any reasonable definition but Abelian, so that the two senses of 'invariant' coincide.)

Comment: @LSpice indeed many non-reductive groups are unimodular (and many are not). For $G(R)$ with $G$ linear algebraic if $G$ has no nontrivial multiplicative character then $G(R)$ is unimodular: this works when $G$ is perfect (e.g. semisimple, but also many semidirect products), and when $G$ is unipotent. Also  many non-nilpotent $G$ are unimodular as well. Actually, every connected Lie group embeds as a normal subgroup of codimension 1 into a unimodular one, and this embedding can be chosen algebraic when $G$ "is" algebraic.

Answer (score 10):

Let $G$ be the „ax+b“ group, i.e., the group of real matrices $\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\
0&1\end{array}\right)$ with $a\not=0$. Then the left invariant volume form is a multiple of $\frac{1}{a^2}dadb$ and the right invariant volume form is a multiple of $\frac{1}{\vert a\vert}dadb$.

This example is taken from the book of Abbaspour-Moskowitz, Chapter 2.